# Drag has reversed direction

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, uikit, swiftui

I created a Game which involves dragging tiles and dropping them, this was created in MacOS. I then re built in IOS exactly the same application, and it uses UIKit as expected. The only issue i have is that when i drag the tiles they are going in the opposite vertical direction.
So i drag up and left, and the tile goes down and left... but when i release, it knows where i am dropping and the tile appears in the correct place.

```
import SwiftUI

 enum DragState {
case unknown
case good
case bad
}

struct Letter: View {
@State private var dragAmount = CGSize.zero
@State private var dragState = DragState.unknown

var text: String
var index: Int

var onChanged: ((CGPoint, String) -> DragState)?
var onEnded: ((CGPoint, Int, String) -> Void)?

var body: some View {
    Image(text)
        .frame(width: 67, height: 97)
        .offset(dragAmount)
        .zIndex(dragAmount == .zero ? 0 : 1)
        .shadow(color: dragColor, radius: dragAmount == .zero ? 0 : 10)
        .shadow(color: dragColor, radius: dragAmount == .zero ? 0 : 10)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .global)
                .onChanged {
                    self.dragAmount = CGSize(width: $0.translation.width, height: -$0.translation.height)
                    self.dragState = self.onChanged?($0.location, self.text) ?? .unknown
                }
                .onEnded {
                    if self.dragState == .good {
                        self.onEnded?($0.location, self.index, self.text)
                    }

                    self.dragAmount = .zero
                }

        )


}

var dragColor: Color {
    switch dragState {
    case .unknown:
        return .black
    case .good:
        return .green
    case .bad:
        return .red
    }
}
```

}

So it's just whilst dragging that the tile is visually incorrect.
Is this due to change from Cocoa to UIKit perhaps, and can i therefore change something to solve this?

Many Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I found it, it was simply the line of code

```
self.dragAmount = CGSize(width: $0.translation.width, height: -$0.translation.height)
```

needed changing to

```
self.dragAmount = CGSize(width: $0.translation.width, height: $0.translation.height)
```

Sometimes its stares you in the face

Thanks